# Semantic-UI SASS workflow

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-css

I'm new in Semantic-UI. In Foundation 6 to work with SASS you edit _settngs.scss to customize. What is the equivalent LESS file in Semantic-UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html

To make changes you need to alter any of the appropriate files in the following directory.

```
/semantic/src/site
```

For instance, we changed the global font size and color of red by altering

```
/semantic/src/site/globals/site.variables
```

and adding

```
@emSize: 16px;
@red: #F44336;
```

You'll have to rebuild your .less files obviously once you make the changes.